# Should typings be committed? If no, how to trigger typings install on npm install without breaking users?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an npm package (X) which is written with Typescript and uses types installed with [typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings).

I have not committed the typings directory generated by typings because I have a typings.json from which the typings tool can re-generate that directory. In fact, I added typings as a devDependency and an npm script "postinstall" to run "typings install", so any new developers can have everything set up after they run "npm install" on a fresh checkout.

The problem is, there's another package using this one (e.g. Y). When a user goes to "npm install Y", they pull down X and the "postinstall" script is running on their machines. Typings is a devDependency so it's not downloaded (nor do I want it to be for them - they're not developing on X). Nor do they have typings installed globally, so their install of Y errors out.

What's the proper solution? Should I commit typings? Or is there another npm lifecycle script which only runs after install if "npm install" with no args is executed? Or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9184

Comment: Hi Paleo. So there's currently no solution for this? (and the solution is coming with Typescript 2.0?). If so, can you submit that as an answer so I can close this question. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure of the solution, I just wanted to say that the solution will probably change in the next weeks.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway Paleo

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `typings` at runtime. They are only used by TypeScript in the dev environment. After you compile `.ts` to `.js`, there is no need for `typings` anymore.

So, no, don't commit `typings`.

Comment: Hi Mihai. I understand that and that's what I'm currently doing. Is there a way to automate downloading of types with `npm install` for developers working on the package but avoid this for users of the package?

Comment: Is `npm install --production --ignore-scripts` what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't think so. Most likely it's as Paleo pointed out. There will be a proper solution (without the use of npm scripts) once Typescript types are treated like packages on npm (since they can then be listed as devDependencies). Thanks about those flags though. Didn't know about --ignore-scripts